# Can you identify this yarn tool?

Tags: knitting, crocheting, yarn, tool-identification, fiber-crafts

I’ve been knitting, crocheting, sewing, weaving, and most other things textile related for decades and have never come across this tool. I inherited a box of yarn and other crafting items that included this in a sealed bag with three small balls of yarn and a yarn needle. I have never seen one of these before. Can anyone tell me what it is?[image]

Comment: How sure are you that it's a yarn tool? Is it only because you found it among yarn and a yarn needle? I'm simply wondering if that could exclude the right answer. It might be better to leave that limitation out of the title.

Comment: Can you maybe show the side of the tool? Does it have a small gap towards the front? I have seen similar tools which could be used to hold a blade to undo seams.

Comment: I wonder if this would help turn a collar, to get a sharp point?

Comment: I would guess that it's a yarn pick (maybe?) used to pick up stitches if dropped but not unraveled and used for loom knitting.

Answer (score 4):

That looks like a bone folder (aka paper creaser) to me. A plastic version though, not actual bone. I've got one that's similar in bright orange, although mine doesn't have the notch near the  tip.

It definitely comes under 'other crafting items" rather than yarn related though. It should be blunt, because they're used for making creases in paper without puncturing it, so that the paper can be folded more easily. Think book binding, card making etc.

Honestly, I'm not surprised it showed up in a bunch of unrelated crafting stuff; they're slippery critters, prone to wandering off and reappearing somewhere else entirely.